# What is the fastest way to level in Destiny 2?

Tags: destiny-2

I recently bought Destiny 2 for Xbox One and my friends are all at max level. I want to be able to do strikes/raids with them. What is the fastest way of leveling in Destiny 2?

Comment: Levelling to max and having the Power required to do endgame content like Raids are two seperate beasts. You might be better off asking about a good way to get your Power to around 300 (or whatever the current raid suggested level is) than hitting level 20.

Comment: @Zodack I am assuming Destiny 2 is similar to WoW where power level = item level? What is the average power level for a fresh 20?

Comment: Power is an aggregate of the Attack and Defense values of all your gear, yeah. I would say an average power for a fresh level 20 is around 200-230. It becomes more of an issue of how to acquire higher Power gear once you hit max level quickly.

Comment: How is power level determined for dropped gear? Is it RNG? Also are the items stats randomized like Diablo or set pieces like WoW?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am going to answer this from personal experience from leveling up 6 characters, it is possible there is something I'm overlooking or that theoretically there is a faster way if you maximize time.

The fastest way I've found is to first finish the story. Each story mission gives you a lot of experience. You don't even have to kill all enemies unless it specifically tells you to, you can avoid them and just get to the end. But this will mean you might have to do some adventures or public events to level up enough to access the next story mission.

Once you beat the story and get to level 20 your next mission is to get to raising your power level. "Powerful gear" AKA Luminous engrams are your main goal, these will give you legendary (and sometimes exotic) gear at a power level higher than your current max. You can get a number of them each week by completing milestones. An easy one to get is by joining an active clan and once members of the clan complete weekly milestones (even without you being there or online) they will unlock and give you the rewards. There's also exotic quests which lead you to guaranteed higher level gear and unique exotics that you can only get through the quests.

After climbing high enough you'll be able to play end game activities such as Nightfalls or Raids. Completing these weekly will not only give you more luminous engrams but these kinds of actives also have a higher chance at giving you exotics. Rise and repeat each week getting as many luminous engrams as possible and with enough time (and luck) you'll be at max power level soon.

Comment: Thank you for the response! So is the power level of the gear dropped dependent on the power level I am currently wearing? Ie its always a bit better, but you won't find a crazy high PL item if you are low?

Comment: Almost correct yes, when you get a luminous engram or exotic it will be a little bit higher than your MAX power level. Meaning the game is smart enough to see what gear you have equipped, unequipped, or stored in the vault so you don't always have to have your best gear equipped at all times. It will see figure out what your max is and give you slightly higher.

Comment: Ah okay, so should I keep a set of gear stored in my vault that maximizes my power level so each exotic will be the best possible?

Comment: With how you'll be getting new gear and needing to get rid of older, less powerful ones you won't need to keep much in the vault at first unless you like how to looks/shoots/ect. You'll get to the point where you might be getting a higher level of the same gear a few times so you don't have to get too attached and store it all right away.

Answer (score 4):

Play through the main game. Completing the core storyline automatically advances you to 20.

Comment: How long does the campaign usually take? Do different difficulties grant more/less experience?

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. You only have to be level 15 to finish the campaign, and there's no immediate jump to 20 upon doing so.